# How do I exclude a hook from a production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a hook that prints some debug information, which in turn calls some of Reacts hooks. I would like to automatically exclude it from the production build. If I try to do it with an if statement like this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        useMyHook(...)
}
```

I get the error  `React Hook "useMyHook" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render`. In this case the hooks would still be called in order though.

How can I exclude a hook in a production build?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the logic inside `useMyHook` with `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')` condition.

You can check out [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) from React documentation for a neat explanation.

Comment: `useMyHook` in turns uses other hooks. So I would have to have them too outside of the if statement. Which means means most of the `useMyHook` would still be run in production.